# Can Python parallelize calls to C functions via ctypes for speed?

Tags: python, optimization, dll, parallel-processing, ctypes

Is it possible to use parallelization to speed up calls to functions defined in compiled C code that is imported via ctypes?

To explain my question, here is a basic example, showing example C code which is compiled and then imported via Python:

```
// my_c_code.cpp
#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLLEXPORT double sum(double a, double b) {
return a + b;
}
```

And the Python code:

```
// my_python_code.py
dll = ctypes.WinDLL("my_c_code_compiled.dll")
func = dll.sum
func.restype = c_double
func.argtypes = [c_double, c_double]

// An example function call is then: func(1.1, 2.2)
// which will return 3.3
```

The above code works for single inputs. But let's say I have 2 arrays to add:

```
input1 = np.array([1.1, 1.0, 1.3])
input2 = np.array([2.2, 2.0, 2.3])
// the output when added should be [3.3, 3, 3.6]
```

I could obviously add the arrays using my C function with a loop. However, since all items in the array are independent, there's no need to do them one at a time. Therefore, is it possible to tell Python to compute func() on the arrays in parallel or using multiple cores to speed things up?

I appreciate we could simply re-write the above function to be parallelized in C. However, in practice, my C code is much more complex than the above and this is not an option - I'm therefore interested in telling Python to call it many times in parallel if possible?

Thanks

Comment: ctypes releases the global interpreter lock (GIL) while a C call is executed so it should work if the main work is done in C.

Comment: But I guess that would require re-writing the C code then? Is there a quick "python fix" instead? Thanks

Comment: This is hard to tell without knowing the real C code. The shown code only uses the input values to calculate an output value independent from any other data in memory and wouldn't need a rewrite.

Comment: Are you sure you can improve more than what *NumPy* is already doing?